# solving over determined non-linear equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

Actually I have to calculate values of 3 variables from probably 8 or 9 non-linear equations(may be more for accuracy).

I was using lsqnonlin and fsolve. 
Using lsqnonlin, it says solver stopped prematurely (mainly due to value of iteration, funEvals and tolerance) and the output is far away from exact solution. I tried but I don't know on what basis I should set those parameters.

Using fsolve, it says no solution found.

I also used LMFnlsq and LMFsolve but it gives the output nowhere near the exact solution? I tried to change other parameters too but I could not bring those solutions to my desired values.

Is there any other way to solve these overdetermined non-linear equations?

**My code till now:**

```
x0 = [20 40 275];

eqn = @(x)[((((x(1)-Sat(1,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(1,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(1,3))^2))-dis(1)^2);
    ((((x(1)-Sat(2,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(2,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(2,3))^2))-dis(2)^2);
    ((((x(1)-Sat(3,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(3,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(3,3))^2))- dis(3)^2);    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(4,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(4,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(4,3))^2))- dis(4))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(5,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(5,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(5,3))^2))- dis(5))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(6,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(6,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(6,3))^2))- dis(6))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(7,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(7,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(7,3))^2))- dis(7))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(8,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(8,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(8,3))^2))- dis(8))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(9,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(9,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(9,3))^2))- dis(9))^2;    
    ((((x(1)-Sat(10,1))^2+(x(2)-Sat(10,2))^2+(x(3)-Sat(10,3))^2))- dis(10))^2];

lb = [0 0 0];
ub = [100 100 10000];

options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','MaxFunEvals',3000,'MaxIter',700,'TolFun',1e-18);%,'TolX',1);

x= lsqnonlin(eqn,x0,lb,ub,options)

**Error:**

**Solver stopped prematurely.**

lsqnonlin stopped because it exceeded the iteration limit,
options.MaxIter = 700 (the selected value).


x =   20.349       46.633       9561.5
```

Hoping for some suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you've tried. It's impossible to suggest things if we haven't seen what you've tried so far.

Comment: You *might* get a better response at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have added some of the code I have done. Hope this would work @rayryeng

Comment: @Prajan did you try to use only three first equations (or last three or any three)?

Comment: @brainkz Ya it works with first three equation. But, when I add 4th equation it starts to go out of exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually model this explicitly:

```
min w'w
f_i(x) = w_i
w is a free variable
L<=x<=U
```

It should be easy to calculate a feasible (but non-optimal) solution in advance. If you can find a "good" initial solution that would be even better. Then use a general purpose NLP solver (e.g. `fmincon`) and pass on your initial feasible solution (both `x` and `w`). The best thing is to use a modeling system that allows automatic differentiation. Otherwise you should provide correct and precise gradients (and if needed second derivatives). See also the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559301/minimizing-functions-with-large-gradients-using-scipy-optimize-minimize/35569177#35569177).